# XSLT listing in Umbraco

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

I have this structure:

```
<EmployeeArea id="1188" level="2" nodeName="Ansatte" urlName="ansatte">

  <EmployeeDepartment id="1189" level="3" nodeName="Ledelse" urlName="ledelse">

    <Employee id="1191" level="4" nodeName="Tommy Pophead" urlName="tommy-pophead" />

    <Employee id="1193" level="4" nodeName="Test Person" urlName="test-person" />

  </EmployeeDepartment>

  <EmployeeDepartment id="1190" level="3" nodeName="Salg" urlName="salg">

    <Employee id="1192" level="4" nodeName="Lars Rocker" urlName="lars-rocker" />

  </EmployeeDepartment>

</EmployeeArea>
```

How would you guys do this in XSLT?

I'm thinking something like a for each that loops through the childs of Employees and then a foreach in that foreach that loops through the childs of the departments? But is that the smartest way?

Want it shown on the page like this:

Employees page:

- Finance

-- Person 1 - phone number - emailaddress

-- Person 2

- Sales

-- Person 4 - phone number - emailaddress

-- Person 5 - phone number - emailaddress

Comment: It's a bad definition. You should provide sample of XML input, and the desired result. As code.

Comment: Is this better? Or do you want the HTML output?

Comment: @Daniel. Much more. But if you want a precise html format, you should provide it also. Do note that's an XSLT question, not a question off CSS design for example.

Comment: I don't need the precise HTML, just a XSLT transformation that can group the persons under the correct departments. :)

Comment: @Daniel. Ok, I see. But it seems that they are already grouped in XML. Grouping problem in XSLT usually occurs with a flat structure of XML, which is not the case. If the grouping is already sufficient, you just need to translate XML elements to HTML tags. Is this the matter?

Comment: I guess so :) - just can't really get it right.

Comment: @Daniel, then my answer can be helpful. Do check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would exploit built-in rules.

E.g this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vBaseLink" select="'http://localhost/'"/>

    <xsl:template match="EmployeeArea">
        <body>
            <h1>
                <a href="{$vBaseLink}{@urlName}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
                </a>
            </h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EmployeeDepartment">
        <h2>
            <a href="{$vBaseLink}{@urlName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
        </h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <div>
            <a href="{$vBaseLink}{@urlName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Against your sample will provide this result:

```
<body>
    <h1>
        <a href="http://localhost/ansatte">Ansatte</a>
    </h1>
    <h2>
        <a href="http://localhost/ledelse">Ledelse</a>
    </h2>
    <div>
        <a href="http://localhost/tommy-pophead">Tommy Pophead</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://localhost/test-person">Test Person</a>
    </div>
    <h2>
        <a href="http://localhost/salg">Salg</a>
    </h2>
    <div>
        <a href="http://localhost/lars-rocker">Lars Rocker</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is specific to Umbraco, and I've recently been working with it, I'll add a more Umbraco-specific answer, in case others are looking for a complete solution.

Please note that XSLT is a "Template" type language, it finds the strongest match for each node and applies that template. This allows for some fun customisation (e.g. one template for normal employees, but a special template for CIO/CEO/Managers etc). Please take a look at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) for more information.

Given your structure above I can tell that **Departments** and **Employees** are nodes in your Umbraco content tree, sitting below the **EmployeeArea** node. Assuming this is XSLT to apply to the **EmployeeArea** as the **$currentPage** variable, the following would work well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets"
  xmlns:MyEmployeeLibrary="urn:MyEmployeeLibrary"
  exclude-result-prefixes="MyEmployeeLibrary msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets ">

  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>Employees page:</h1>
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/EmployeeDepartment" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EmployeeDepartment">
    <li>
      <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
      </a>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Employee" />
      </ul>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employee">
    <li>
      <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
        <!-- 
          Your sample XML didn't include phone/email, but your output requests it.
          Let's assume you've created your own XSLT Extension to get this information.
        -->
        <xsl:value-of select="MyEmployeeLibrary:GetDetailsForList(@id)"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For more information on creating a custom XSLT Extension for Umbraco, check the developer training videos in the [UmbracoTV](http://umbraco.org/products/umbracotv) section (it's really easy, and if you are running 4.6.1 you just drop your DLL in the \bin\ folder and it works).

NOTE: I've used nested UL tags here, you can change it to any HTML you like, DIV tags with a CSS Class assigned is my preferred method.